# Add line numbers to final nonempty lines using bash

Tags: bash, awk, replace

Is there a way to add line numbers to a file, but only have it start from the line after the last blank line? For example

```
aaa
bbb

ccc

ddd
eee
```

would become

```
aaa
bbb

ccc

1. ddd
2. eee
```

since the line `ddd` is the first line after the last blank line.

Right now, I'm going through file by file to do this using vim (by selecting the lines and doing a quick command), but I have 1,000 files I need to run through and I'd prefer not having to do it individually by hand, but can't think of how to get around it.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with `sed`, it can't do arithmetic. Try `awk`.

Comment: I'm not really used to using awk so not sure how that would be done. I'll update the tags.

Comment: A basic problem is that any sequential tool has no way of knowing whena blank line is the last one. So you need to do two passes: first find the line number of the last blank, then use that as a parameter the second time to add numbers after it.

Comment: It's easier if you can use a real programming language like Python or PHP. It can read the entire file into memory, split it into blocks at blank lines, then add line numbers to the last block.

Comment: Not necessarily, one thing you can easily do is just reverse the number of lines, find the first blank line, then reverse all lines again and add numbers backwards from the bottom line. Should be possible "easily", problem is I'm not very used to bashing so don't know how to approach that.

Comment: Even that is tricky because you need to know how many lines are in the last block so you can assign line numbers in reverse

Comment: You just grab the line number of the first empty line (after reversal). That's not to hard to grab. You can set that into a variable then use that number.

Comment: But then you have to go back and number the lines before it.

Comment: Yes, or you can just number the lines in the original file accordingly. To get the line number you can just run:
`tac filename | grep -n "^$" | head -n 1 | sed -E 's/([^:]*):.*/\1/'`
You can save that into a variable and then number the last var lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it simply with `awk` and three-rules, including the `END` rule to number the final group of lines, e.g.

```
awk '
    NF > 0  { a[++n]=$0 }
    NF == 0 { for(i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[i]; print""; n=0 }
    END     { for(i=1; i<=n; i++) printf "%d. %s\n", i, a[i]}
' file
```

**Explanation**

- For the first rule `NF > 0`, if there is at least one field (line non-empty), store the line in the array `a` and pre-increment counter `n` (to keep consistent with `awk` `1 to NF` indexing)
- For the second rule `NF == 0` if the line is blank, output what you have stored in `a` and then output an empty-line and reset `n` to zero;
- Finally, in the `END` rule, number and output all lines stored in `a`.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk '
>     NF > 0  { a[++n]=$0 }
>     NF == 0 { for(i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[i]; print""; n=0 }
>     END     { for(i=1; i<=n; i++) printf "%d. %s\n", i, a[i]}
> ' file
aaa
bbb

ccc

1. ddd
2. eee
```

Comment: You are welcome -- though if you are putting in within a loop -- you may want to consider writing your entire script as an `awk` script. If your files are large, doing it that will will improve efficiency by orders of magnitude `:)`

Comment: The files generally have under 60 lines, so they're fairly small. So the for loop isn't to bad for efficiency. Thanks for the option though! I'll keep that in mind for next time.

Comment: You are good then. Anything over 1000 lines, you start thinking about it, 10,000 lines it starts to really matter, and by 100K lines, you can go get coffee while your script is running while you think about it...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `awk`.

```
awk '!NF{x=NR} {r[NR]=$0} 
     END {for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) print (i>x? (++n)". "r[i]: r[i])}' file
```

We store the rows to array. At the `END`, `x` will be the last blank number line, so we print the numbering for line numbers greater than `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a two pass version that does not require reading the entire file into memory. If it is a *large* file, you might want to consider memory:

```
awk '   NR==FNR {if (/^[ \t]*$/) ll=FNR; next}
        FNR>ll {c++}
        {printf "%s%s\n", (c ? c "." OFS : ""), $0}' file file
```

Prints:

```
aaa
bbb

ccc

1. ddd
2. eee
```

With `sed` and `tail` you can calculate the last blank line like so:

```
$ sed -n '/^[[:blank:]]*$/=' file | tail -1
5
```

Which you can use to set a variable for `awk` as well:

```
awk -v ll=$(sed -n '/^[[:blank:]]*$/=' file | tail -1) '
            FNR>ll {c++}
            {printf "%s%s\n", (c ? c "." OFS : ""), $0}' file
```

In any case, you can only do one of two things: Hold the entire file in memory and print after reading it all or read it twice. In most cases, it is better to read it twice since it will not impact memory and it is usually just as fast (since most OSs will cache the file.)

---

Just to compare some timings of read whole file vs read it twice consider a 100 line file (likely too fast to accurate measure):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {for (i=1; i<=101; i++) print i%3 ? i : ""}' >/tmp/file
```

Now time that with the read all vs read twice solutions:

```
time awk -v ll=$(sed -n '/^[[:blank:]]*$/=' file | tail -1) '
            FNR>ll {c++}
            {printf "%s%s\n", (c ? c "." OFS : ""), $0}' file > /dev/null
            
time awk '
    NF > 0  { a[++n]=$0 }
    NF == 0 { for(i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[i]; print""; n=0 }
    END     { for(i=1; i<=n; i++) printf "%d. %s\n", i, a[i]}
' file > /dev/null

time awk '   NR==FNR {if (/^[ \t]*$/) ll=FNR; next}
    FNR>ll {c++}
    {printf "%s%s\n", (c ? c "." OFS : ""), $0}' file file  > /dev/null
```

Prints:

```
real    0m0.012s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.007s

real    0m0.007s
user    0m0.003s
sys 0m0.003s

real    0m0.007s
user    0m0.003s
sys 0m0.003s
```

Now try with 100,001 lines:

```
awk 'BEGIN { for (i=1; i<=100001; i++) print i%3 ? i : ""}' >/tmp/file

time awk -v ll=$(sed -n '/^[[:blank:]]*$/=' file | tail -1) '
            FNR>ll {c++}
            {printf "%s%s\n", (c ? c "." OFS : ""), $0}' file > /dev/null
            
time awk '
    NF > 0  { a[++n]=$0 }
    NF == 0 { for(i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[i]; print""; n=0 }
    END     { for(i=1; i<=n; i++) printf "%d. %s\n", i, a[i]}
' file > /dev/null

time awk '   NR==FNR {if (/^[ \t]*$/) ll=FNR; next}
    FNR>ll {c++}
    {printf "%s%s\n", (c ? c "." OFS : ""), $0}' file file  > /dev/null
```

Times:

```
real    0m0.081s
user    0m0.079s
sys 0m0.007s

real    0m0.047s
user    0m0.042s
sys 0m0.004s

real    0m0.058s
user    0m0.052s
sys 0m0.004s
```

Now 10,000,001 lines:

```
awk 'BEGIN { for (i=1; i<=10000001; i++) print i%3 ? i : ""}' >/tmp/file

time awk -v ll=$(sed -n '/^[[:blank:]]*$/=' file | tail -1) '
            FNR>ll {c++}
            {printf "%s%s\n", (c ? c "." OFS : ""), $0}' file > /dev/null
            
time awk '
    NF > 0  { a[++n]=$0 }
    NF == 0 { for(i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[i]; print""; n=0 }
    END     { for(i=1; i<=n; i++) printf "%d. %s\n", i, a[i]}
' file > /dev/null

time awk '   NR==FNR {if (/^[ \t]*$/) ll=FNR; next}
    FNR>ll {c++}
    {printf "%s%s\n", (c ? c "." OFS : ""), $0}' file file  > /dev/null
```

Times:

```
real    0m6.766s
user    0m7.671s
sys 0m0.063s

real    0m3.950s
user    0m3.921s
sys 0m0.026s

real    0m4.801s
user    0m4.754s
sys 0m0.041s
```

So surprisingly, it is slightly faster for a smaller file to read it twice and slightly faster to hold it in memory if larger. This is on a computer with 64GB RAM and an SSD. Smaller memory or slower hard drives would change this.